# How do I get data from a Text Block that is in a Data Template in a List View?

Tags: c#, listview, uwp

I made a list and populated it with the file urls, I want to grab that url from the text block that is in the list inside of that data template but the function that I made for that purpose isn't returning me expected string. It is giving me null instead. The function I used was SelectionChanged property of the ListView

```
<ListView   ItemsSources="{x:Bind noticeData}"
            SelectedIndex="{x:Bind MasterListView.SelectedIndex, Mode=OneWay}"
            x:Name="uriList" SelectionChanged="uriList_SelectionChanged"
            IsItemClickEnabled="True" Grid.Row="3">

            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate x:DataType="data:Datum_2">
                    <StackPanel>
                        <TextBlock x:Name="downFileUri" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0"
                        VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                        Margin="0,0,0,20" Visibility="Visible"
                        Text="{x:Bind file_url}" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>

</ListView>
```

Comment: Could you show us the code of the event handler? What is 'x:Bind'?

Comment: In the future, please paste text as text, not an image. Thanks.

Comment: @JanDotNet [`x:Bind` is a compiled binding](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xaml-platform/x-bind-markup-extension). Win10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When following the [MVVM pattern](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k77dqVVWgB8&list=PLdkt3RKz_b0w9Ouo03ZGMbXIOreJ7bE9C) you will more often than not, skip using control event handlers, such as click events and selection events. Instead, the pattern allows us to bind to properties and capture when those property's change inside the properties setting block.

Instead of binding to the `SelectedIndex` you want to bind to the `SelectedItem`

The `SelectedItem` will be of whatever type your collection is holding. In the below example I assume you have an object called `NoticeData`

```
<ListBox SelectedItem="{Binding MySelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay}">
```

Then in your view model

```
private NoticeData _mySelectedItem;

public NoticeData MySelectedItem
{
   get{ return _mySelectedItem; }
   set{ _mySelectedItem = value;}
}
```

Here is the MSDN documentation on [ListBox](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox(v=vs.110).aspx) as you will see there is both `SelectedItem` and `SelectedItems` properties. These can both be bound to. `SelectedItems` of course is used if you enable multiple selection.

Something else you will likely need to consider is implementing INotifyPropertyChanged on your ViewModel if you haven't already.

Here is the [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229614(v=vs.100).aspx) for that as well

**Edit based on comments**

There is an alternative method that you can use for binding as well.

If you wish to bind another element to your selected item you just need to name your element.

```
  <ListBox x:Name="MyListBox" ItemsSource="{Binding myItems}"/>

  <TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=MyListBox, Path=SelectedItem.WhatEverProperty}"/>
```

Comment: SelectedIndex is used just so I could reflect selection that are made in MasterListView and uriListView so that they will both have same selected index

Comment: @user3024610 you will still want to use SelectedItem to capture the content of the selected item. You can bind to them both if you'd like. It's harmless

Comment: @Anthony_Russel that's not what I had in my mind but I think you just gave me an awesome idea. Thanks ^_^ 

Could you send the code for how I could bind SelectedItem so to a TextBlock ??

Comment: @user3024610 I updated the answer. If this works for you please don't forget to upvote and checkmark as the answer. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, will do that, just one question. I don't get the WhatEverProperty part, I don't know what property will return me text from the selected item :/

Comment: I put the whatever property because it depends on what properties you have created on your object. If your listbox is populated with a bunch of NoticeDataModel objects then the SelectedItem will return the selected NoticeDataModel. So if you wanted to bind to your file_url Property on NoticeDataModel it would be SelectedItem.file_url

Comment: It WORKED !! ^_^ ^_^_^_^__^_^_^_^_^_^_^_^ YAYYYYYYY

THANK YOU SOOOOOOO MUCH !! Gonna upvote and select as answer as stuff. You are soooo awesome ^_^